# Aggregating an Generic Column in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

We have a table that collects counts from sensors attached to embedded computers.  I have a table with the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE Demo (
  PKColumn BIGINT
  , FKColumn INT
  , ...
  , EventDateTime DATETIME
  , Count1 INT
  , Count2 INT
  , Count3 INT
  , Count4 INT
)
```

The problem is, for FKColumn = 1 a net count would be (Count1 + Count3) - (Count2 + Count4). But for FKColumn = 2, the net count would be (Count2 + Count4) - (Count1 + Count3).  The data is streaming in from an embedded computer, and based on how the sensors on that computer are calibrated, we can get different definitions as to what each count means.

Luckily, once the sensors are installed, they never change.

Unfortunately, there is a lack of control in how the sensors are installed...thus the problem.

Since the definitions of each column can differ for every FKColumn Value, what's the most performant way of building my aggregate functions.  I was considering a mapping table to define what each sensor for each FKColumn is, but as I built that solution, it looked as if the lookup for each calculation was going to cost too much.

The database is running in Azure, so no CLR functions.

Has anyone else faced this situation? How did you solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Create a mapping table like so:

```
CREATE TABLE Map
(
  PKColumn INT NOT NULL 
  , Count1 INT NOT NULL 
  , Count2 INT NOT NULL 
  , Count3 INT NOT NULL 
  , Count4 INT NOT NULL 
)
```

Based on your example, populate with:

```
INSERT INTO MAP (Count1, Count2, Count3, Count4)
VALUES (1, -1, 1, -1)

INSERT INTO MAP (Count1, Count2, Count3, Count4)
VALUES (-1, 1, -1, 1)
```

Then create a view:

```
CREATE View DemoSum
AS
SELECT CountSum = (m.Count1*d.Count1 + m.Count2*d.Count2 + 
                   m.Count3*d.Count3 + m.Count4*d.Count4)
       , d.PKColumn
       , d.FKColumn
FROM Demo d
INNER JOIN Map m ON m.PKColumn = d.FKColumn
```

[You might need to take into account nulls in your Demo table count columns.]

Comment: I like that, what's funny is I had a similar thought last night while sleeping.  Weird that solutions come easier when you aren't concentrating on them.

Comment: Luckily the counts are always >=0, no NULLs!

Comment: OK, using this method we can compute aggregates against 14M rows in 1983 ms.  Nice!

Comment: I wrapped the logic in a table valued function, it increased execution time and CPU cost, but now we can call the aggregate functions from anywhere, and get the same counts each time! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to create a table called multipliers with the structure similar to:

```
CREATE TABLE multipliers (
 FKColumn INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
 Mult1 INT,
 Mult2 INT,
 Mult3 INT,
 Mult4 INT)
```

Then define the values for the Mult1 through to Mult4 as 1 or -1. For the provided example the values will be:

```
INSERT INTO multipliers (FKColumn, Mult1, Mult2, Mult3, Mult4) 
VALUES(1, 1, -1, 1, -1);
INSERT INTO multipliers (FKColumn, Mult1, Mult2, Mult3, Mult4) 
VALUES(2, -1, 1, -1, 1);
```

And then all you have to do is JOIN the tables:

```
SELECT a.FKColumn, 
Count1 * Mult1 + Count2 * Mult2 + Count3 * Mult3 + Count4 * Mult4 AS net
FROM Demo a, multipliers b 
WHERE a.FKColumn = b.FKColumn
```

Comment: beat you to it :), but +1 from me. (Please convert to use ANSI join syntax)